# For a bilinear functional why we have $b(x,Ay) = b(A^Tx,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, bilinear-form

For a bilinear functional, or an inner product, why we have $b(x,Ay) = b(A^Tx,y)$, or $(x,Ay)_\Omega = (A^Tx,y)_\Omega$, for a matrix $A$?

Comment: You don't. Let $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$, $b(x,y)=2x_1y_1+x_2y_2$, and let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $b(x,Ay)=2x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ but $b(A^Tx,y)=2x_2y_1+x_1y_2$. The desired property only holds for the standard inner product $b(x,y)=x^Ty$.

Comment: You don't have that in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rahul pointed out in the comments what you have written is in general false. But if we restrict ourselfs to $b$ being the euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ it becomes correct. You just have to write the inner product as matrix multiplications:
$$(x,Ay)=x^T(Ay)=x^TAy=(A^Tx)^Ty=(A^Tx,y).$$

If you talk about a general $b$ and a linear continuous map $A$ you can define the adjoint of $A$ (denoted with $A^*$) with respect to $b$ by having to satisfy
$$b(x,Ay)=b(A^*x,y).$$
Hence if $b$ is the euclidean inner product as above you have $A^*=A^T$.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint for more details